# How to create an alias from an select result in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create an alias from an select result.I've tried to use oracle dynamic query but doesn't working.Here is my sql:

```
declare 
    v_a varchar2(50);
    sql_smt varchar2(200);
begin
    select TO_CHAR('#'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-30,'yyyymmdd')||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate+2,'yyyymmdd')) INTO v_a from dual;
    sql_smt :='SELECT sysdate as :1 FROM dual';
    execute immediate sql_smt using v_a;
end;
```

I want to reach to an result like in the photo.
Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: What you mean isnt working? Error? wrong result? What you want?

Comment: You can only use bind variables for values, not object names, including aliases. I don't see what you're trying to achieve though - you're going to have to select that dynamic SQL into a PL/SQL variable anyway, so it's that PL/SQL variable name that matters, not the column expression alias (if it has one at all)? Please explain (in your question) what you're actually trying to achieve overall, not *just* your current attempt to solve whatever problem you actually have.

Comment: Can you check now? I've made an edit :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tagged this for SQL Developer you could use (ab)use substitution variables for this; in your worksheet do:

```
column x_title new_value y_title noprint;

select TO_CHAR('#'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-30,'yyyymmdd')||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate+2,'yyyymmdd'))
  as x_title
from dual;

set verify off

select sysdate as "&y_title" from dual;
```

which when you run as a script (F5) produces this in the Script Output window:

```
<blank lines ...>




#20190126-
----------
2019-02-25
```

and then if you run the last line again as a statement (control-enter) the Query Result window shows it as you wanted, from the image in your question.

You could also use the `column` command which makes the output in the Script Output closer to what you wanted when run as a script:

```
column sysdate heading &y_title
select sysdate from dual;

#20190126-20190227
------------------
2019-02-25
```

but then when run as a statement the Query Results window doesn't honour that heading.

Note that this is all client-specific functionality, not SQL - it will work in SQL Developer, and the script versions will work in SQL*Plus and SQLcl, but not in other clients (unless they have tried to feature-match SQL*Plus to some extent).

If you aren't only going to be viewing the results in one of those clients but actually want to end up, say, pulling them into an application over JDBC or whatever, then other solutions would be more appropriate. Generating a ref cursor with the column as the name you want would be fairly simple. But that's not what you've asked for...

---

OK, since you asked in a comment, you can open a ref cursor in an anonymous block:

```
var rc refcursor

declare 
  l_alias varchar2(50);
begin
  select TO_CHAR('#'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-30,'yyyymmdd')||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate+2,'yyyymmdd'))
  into l_alias
  from dual;

  open :rc for 'SELECT sysdate as "' || l_alias || '" FROM dual';
end;
/


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print rc

#20190127-
----------
2019-02-26
```

or without the local variable:

```
var rc refcursor

begin
  open :rc for 'SELECT sysdate as "'
    || TO_CHAR('#'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-30,'yyyymmdd')||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate+2,'yyyymmdd'))
    || '" FROM dual';
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


print rc;

#20190127-
----------
2019-02-26
```

Again `var[iable]` and `print` are client-specific commands; and I don't think there's a way to get the results in the Query Results grid with this approach. But you can use the same anonymous block approach from other clients or applications; e.g. from JDBC you could have a statement as:

```
String sql = "begin open ? for 'SELECT sysdate as \"'"
    + "|| TO_CHAR('#'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-30,'yyyymmdd')||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate+2,'yyyymmdd'))"
    + "|| '\" FROM dual'; end;";
```

and then bind the `?` parameter placeholder as a cursor type before executing. That probably isn't very useful though as you'd have to examine the metadata to find the column alias anyway, and you could generate it on the application side using the application language tools (e..g Java date manipulation).

You could also create a function that returns a ref cursor, which you could then call from a plain query (instead of an anonymous block), which would allow you to see it in the Query Results grid - possibly with an extra step to show the cursor result. But you made not need that extra level of code or want another object to be created in your DB.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct.Can you add an example with ref cursor?I think this post will help many persons.I'm a little bit curious about implementation.If you can of course :)

Comment: @ggigle - OK, added a basic example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
declare 
  col_hdr   varchar2(50);
  sys_date  varchar2(26);
  sql_smt   varchar2(200);
begin
  select TO_CHAR('#'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-30,'yyyymmdd')||'-'||TO_CHAR(sysdate+2,'yyyymmdd')) INTO col_hdr from dual;
  sql_smt :='SELECT sysdate ' || ' as "' || col_hdr || '" FROM dual';
  dbms_output.put_line(sql_smt);
  execute immediate sql_smt into sys_date; 
  dbms_output.put_line('done');
end;
```

Comment: It works well.But is possible to display result like in the picture?

Comment: I thought you would ask something like that so I researched creating a dynamic column alias that could be used in a simple select statement and I don't think it can be done. You would need to use a ref cursor or some other construct that returns a dynamic results set to a calling program such as C#. There might be a way to combine the execute immediate with a table valued function that would return a dynamic column alias but that would take a few hours of research and testing.